# SeleniumBase get_text()

Tags: css-selectors, seleniumbase

this is my html,I would like to take the " + " sign, but it doesn't work with Full xpath
I need to know what position it is in " + ", whether after the first image or the second or third:

```
<div\><h3 class="text-center"≥ == $0
" XXXXXXXXXXX"
<br>
<img src="data: image/j.peg; base64,/xxxxxxxx==">
<img src="data: image/ipeg; base64,/xxxxxxxx==">
" + "
«img src="data: image/jpeg;base64,/xxxxxxxxx==" style="height:50px;"\>
</h3>
</div>
```

that's my code :
sb.get_text('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h3/text()[2]')

That's the error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/base_case.py", line 1817, in get_text
element = page_actions.wait_for_element_visible(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/page_actions.py", line 508, in wait_for_element_visible
timeout_exception(NoSuchElementException, message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/page_actions.py", line 266, in timeout_exception
raise exc(msg)
seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
Element {/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h3/text()[2]} was not present after 10 seconds
Can't seem to find the '+' sign